# invalid location passed in, must give absolute path?

Tags: python, eclipse, components

I am trying to run a python sandbox example for Redhawk (https://redhawksdr.github.io/Documentation/mainch3.html#x5-270003.3). I could start REDHAWK IDE from /usr/local/redhawk/ide/2.1.2 folder (./eclipse). However, when I run the following command, I got an error:

```
>>> sb.IDELocation("/usr/local/redhawk/ide/2.1.2/eclipse")
IDELocation(): ERROR - invalid location passed in, must give absolute path 
/usr/local/redhawk/ide/2.1.2/eclipse
```

If I ignore this "IDELocation(): ERROR", I have the following problem by executing Plot() command:

```
>>> sb.IDELocation("/usr/local/redhawk/ide/2.1.2/eclipse")
IDELocation(): ERROR - invalid location passed in, must give absolute path 
/usr/local/redhawk/ide/2.1.2/eclipse
>>> plot = sb.Plot()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/redhawk/core/lib/python/ossie/utils/sb/io_helpers.py", 
    line 1985, in __init__
    raise AssertionError, "Plot():__init__() ERROR - must set environment 
    variable RH_IDE or call IDELocation()"
AssertionError: Plot():__init__() ERROR - must set environment variable 
   RH_IDE or call IDELocation()
```

Does anybody know how to fix the problem here? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I am very confused with this error because I think "/usr/local/redhawk/ide/2.1.2/eclipse" is already an absolute path. Besides, I went to this directory /usr/local/redhawk/ide/2.1.2, "./eclipse" command started the IDE successfully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Examining the [GITHub source file](https://github.com/RedhawkSDR/framework-core/blob/master/src/base/framework/python/ossie/utils/sb/domainless.py) for the error

> IDELocation(): ERROR - invalid location passed in, must give absolute path

reveals that the said error is returned if eclipse is not found in the absolute path that was passed in. So the correct way to call the function in your case would be:

```
sb.IDELocation("/usr/local/redhawk/ide/2.1.2/")
```